# Inspect massive JSON with unknown structure using Python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file that is 130GB with an unknown structure that I want to eventually be able to parse and query. The challenge is that the structure of the object changes several times throughout the file (I think the file is a dump of database tables), so I don't think I can simply chunk it and process it piecemeal since I don't know where one object starts and the other begins.

The file is a public price transparency from a large insurer (here is the [link](https://mrf.healthsparq.com/aetnacvs-egress.nophi.kyruushsq.com/prd/mrf/AETNACVS_I/ALICSI/2022-09-05/inNetworkRates/2022-09-05_6b1b3816-1ed5-4937-887d-5c92d6b6c9f9_Aetna-Life-Insurance-Company.json.gz)). The insurers fought tooth and nail to keep this data private so I expect they had little incentive to make it easily usable.

Any suggestions on a strategy I can use will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I was going to suggest using an online json visualizer but I doubt you'd be able to upload a 130gb file lol. Not sure if there is anything currently that shows the structure of json in python, closest thing may be https://pypi.org/project/PyJSONViewer/

Comment: Have you thought about using Bash? I have heard it is super fast while processing large amounts of data. For what purpose do you want to use the json for?

Comment: I don't think any tool that requires reading the file into memory is going to work, regardless how fast the processing speed is. I think I need some way to read in only limited parts of the file but without knowing anything about what's in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you cant,
You will have to use ijson and emit events parse those events.
lastly the schema you are looking for is here [inn file schema](https://github.com/CMSgov/price-transparency-guide/tree/master/schemas/in-network-rates)